# Android Images displayed from cache appear jagged

Tags: android

I am downloading images the net and saving them in application cache.Below is the code for downloading,saving and displaying on screen.

```
        InputStream is = null;
        URL url1 = new URL(small_img_url);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1
                .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(12000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(12000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        String path = "NEO_IMAGES" + File.separator + "images";
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + path
                + File.separator);
        file.mkdirs();
        File file1 = new File(file, fileName + ".jpg");
        if (file1.exists()) {
            file1.delete();
            Log.e("Image already exist", "deleting image=" + fileName);
        }
        // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        // is, "UTF-8"));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file1);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

        fos.flush();

        fos.close();
        is.close();

                  Uri uriItemIcon = Uri.fromFile(file1);

                  final Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uriItemIcon.getPath());

                  imgItem.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
```

The problem is that some images which are not completely rectangular and have a lot of curves appear jagged.
Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: the problem is not abt loading images..the images have to be loaded before the app opens...it is abt the images appearinmg jagged

Answer (score 0):

hey you do not have to do all this . there are libraries which cache for you . and they are also efficient . one which is great is [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

check it out . if you face any problem you can ask.